# nodejs express res.send downloads the file with the full path as a name

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I must be missing something simple, but I am not able to figure it out.
I am downloading a file to the client using res.send and the download occurs, however the filename of the file is xxx_yyy_zzz_nameofthefile.pdf instead of nameofthefile.pdf which is the correct filename

```
downloadDocument(file){
      return this.http.post(`${this.AUTH_SERVER}/download_doc`, file, {
      responseType: "blob",
      });



exports.download_document = function(req, res){
var filename = req.body;
var mypath = /xxx/yyy/zzz;
var specificNameFile = path.join(__dirname, "../../../../"+mypath+"/"+filename)
res.sendFile(specificNameFile)
```

I also tried

```
res.download('../../../../'+mypath+'/' + myfilename, filename);
```

but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

My problem was on the angular part and not as I believe in the back end.
In the front end I had

```
data => {
        saveAs(data, filenameandpaht);
      },
```

where filenames1 was the whole path plus the name of the file.
once I changed to the correct variable, it work perfectly.

```
data => {
        saveAs(data, filename);
      },
```